# Loop through the Alphabet in PHP to group letters into ranges A-C, C-E etc

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5.3, codeigniter-3

I want to create filters using the alphabet with 3-letter ranges like this: `A-C`,`C-E`,`E-G` etc

This is what I have so far:

```
function get_alphabet()
{
  $alphabet = '';
  for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {  

    $letter = chr($i);
    $alphabet .= '<a title="filter results by letter '.$letter.'" 
href="/business/'.$letter.'"> ';
    $alphabet .= $letter;
    $alphabet .= '</a> | '; 
  }

  return $alphabet;
}
echo get_alphabet();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code

```
function get_alphabet()
{
  $alphabet = '';
  for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i=$i+2) {  

    $letter = chr($i);
    $letter2 =($i+2>=90) ? chr(90) : chr($i+2);

    $links=$letter.'-'.$letter2;
    $alphabet .= '<a title="filter results by letter '.$links.'" 
href="/business/'.$links.'"> ';
    $alphabet .= $links;
    $alphabet .= '</a> | '; 

  }

  return $alphabet;
}
echo get_alphabet();
```

> Output : 
>   A-C | C-E | E-G | G-I | I-K | K-M | M-O | O-Q | Q-S | S-U | U-W | W-Y
>   | Y-Z |

Comment: Thank you so much Ankur its working and thank you so much for instant reply.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting "trick" is that you can group ranges using the pattern:

```
array_chunk(range('A', 'Z'), 3)
```

Just replace `A` and `Z` with the starting and ending points of the range, and `3` with the maximum number of elements in each group.

With this pattern in mind, you can refactor your code into a couple of helpers:

```
function get_links() {
    return array_map(
        function ($range) { return array_shift($range) . '-' . array_pop($range); },
        array_chunk(range('A', 'Z'), 3)
    );
}

function make_link($link) {
    return '<a title="filter results by letter '.$link.'" href="/business/'.$link.'">';
}

echo implode('|', array_map('make_link', get_links()));
```

[See it online at 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/DjHvf)